# vscode global keyboard shortcuts overriding in extension

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I have a set of keybindings in `package.json`,

```json
{
     "command": "md.image",
     "key": "Ctrl+Shift+i"
}, {
    "command": "md.codeblocks",
    "key": "Ctrl+Shift+B"
}
```

This has a problem with other global keyboard shortcuts in vscode, I want to have this overridden in the extension so these keyboards act as the current keyboard mappings for the language its loaded for.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone runs into the same specific example of this that I ran into:

I was trying to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> command to go forward with the [Vim extension](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) in VS Code.

I tried unsuccessfully putting a config with `unset!` in `keybindings.json`.

However I found that `"vim.useCtrlKeys": true` in `settings.json` allows these sorts of ctrl keys to work in the Vim extension  with no other changes necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable existing shortcuts by adding a keybinding entry and prefixing its `command` with a `-`. For example, to disable the builtin global shortcut for `ctrl+n`, add the following entry:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+n", "command": "-cursorDown", "when": "textInputFocus" }
```

You can find the default global entries by selecting "Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" from the Command Palette.